# Bash variable in {$var} brackets reads as %7Bvar%7D?

Tags: bash, cygwin

I am trying to do a for loop, but Cygwin does not understand the `{$var}` syntax.

My command:

```
for f in 'svn ls repo_path'; path/{$f}trunk/path; done

Error svn: E170000: URL path/%7Bvar%7Dtrunk/path doesn't exist
```

The string should come out to be: `path/var/trunk/path`

How can I make the variable + string concatenation work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is `${f}`, not `{$f}`.

If you really want `path/var/trunk/path`, you can simply use `path/$f/trunk/path`. This works whether `$f` end with a slash or not. Bash doesn't mind a double slash.

Also, be careful with [parsing the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

> Actually, now I am having this problem: for f in 'svn ls repo_path'; path/${f}trunk/path; done
>
> Comes out as: path/var/%0Dtrunk/path

`%0D` is a carriage return character. A newline in Windows is `\r\n`, not the expected `\n`.

Try setting

```
IFS=$' \t\r\n'
```

before the for loop.

Comment: Wow... Thank you for pointing that out. Been a long day! Would upvote you if I could.

Comment: Actually, now I am having this problem. See comment below.

Comment: Nevermind, I guess I can't comment because I don't have enough reputation. Sorry for this hard to read question:

Comment: Actually, now I am having this problem:

for f in 'svn ls repo_path'; path/${f}trunk/path; done

Comes out as: path/var/%0Dtrunk/path

(f is "var/" not "var", so path/$f/trunk/path would not work)



NOTICE: The random %0D

Comment: By the way, you can edit your question to incorporate additional information. Just click the **edit** link below the question itself. You should only *answer* your own question if you actually want to post a solution.

Comment: You were right about both things. The for loop works perfectly now. Thank you so much! You saved me a huge headache! Edit: I will keep that in mind for future superuser etiquette.

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad you reminded me! Should have left it as answered in the first place, since you did answer my question. :)